# Removing duplicates from field using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes, cursor

I am using ArcPy with ArcMap.

I need to remove duplicates from a field named "Intersecti"

[image]

Here is my code.  I used list..set. It's not removing any duplicates.

```
import arcpy
duplicates = "G:\\xStreetNew\\Duplicates.shp"
duplicates_List = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(duplicates, ['Intersecti']) as Cur:
 for row in Cur:
    duplicates_List.insert(0,row[0])
    duplicates_List = list(set(duplicates_List))
 print duplicates_List
```

Comment: If you want to change values, you need to use an UpdateCursor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to:

- Use an update cursor
- Split the string into a list
- Remove duplicates
- Put the list back into a string
- Assign the string to that row/field
- Apply the update

Try this:

```
import arcpy
duplicates = "G:\\xStreetNew\\Duplicates.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(duplicates, ['Intersecti']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row[0] = ','.join(list(set(row[0].split(','))))
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Or--for clarity-- you could replace the jumbled, multi-operation line, like this:

```
import arcpy
duplicates = "G:\\xStreetNew\\Duplicates.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(duplicates, ['Intersecti']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        v = row[0]
        v = v.split(',')
        v = list(set(v))
        v = ','.join(v)
        row[0] = v
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: +1, FYI, there is no need to make v into a list.  `','.join(v)` works when v is still a set.

Answer (score 8):

[@Tom's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/186220/115) is great.  However, I'll post how this can be achieved in the field calculator.

It's a simple function:

Codeblock:

```
def delDups(n):
  return ', '.join(set(n.split(', ')))
```

Expression:

```
delDups( !Intersecti!)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This can also be done as a straight expression (no codeblock) using `', '.join( set( !Intersecti!.split(', ' )))`