# Removing duplicate strings from field with Field Calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I tried using the same codeblock as [Removing duplicates from field using ArcPy with ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186215), but it is just copying the contents and not removing duplicates. I think my data is formatted the same.

What am I missing?

Codeblock

```
def delDups(n):
  return ', '.join(set(n.split(', ')))
```

Expression

```
delDups( !Names3! )
```

[image]

Comment: You split should say `" ,"` ie space, comma.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work with your data:

```
', '.join(set(filter(None, [b.strip() for b in n.split(',')])))
```

Strip to remove whitespaces before and after string, filter to remove empty strings, set to remove duplicates and then join back to a comma separated string:

```
a = ",East pass ,Iris Bloom Cir ,East pass"
', '.join(set(filter(None, [b.strip() for b in a.split(',')])))
'Iris Bloom Cir, East pass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the two suggestions to work, but I had success when I reformatted the data with "&" [image]

and used:

```
def delDups(n):
 return ' & '.join(set(n.split(' & ')))
```